# Failing to compile a multifile program in c with make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to compile the following multi-file program (taken from the book *Programming: a Modern approach*, second edition By K. N. King) with a Makefile, but the compilation fails and I get the following warnings and don't understand why:

```
clang: warning: readline.o: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: inventory2.o: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Wall' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

here is the makefile:

```
############
# makefile #
############

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -Wall

BIN=inventory2

$(BIN): $(BIN).o readline.o #readline.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) readline.o $(BIN).o -o $(BIN)

$(BIN).o: $(BIN).c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN).c -o $(BIN).o

readline.o: readline.c readline.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) readline.c -o readline.o

clean:
    $(RM) -rf $(BIN) *.dSYM
    $(RM) -rf readline.o
    $(RM) -rf $(BIN).o

run: all
    ./$(BIN)
```

Here are the source files (**inventory2.c**, **readline.c** and **readline.h**)

```
/*********************************************************
 * From C PROGRAMMING: A MODERN APPROACH, Second Edition *
 * By K. N. King                                         *
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 1996 W. W. Norton & Company, Inc. *
 * All rights reserved.                                  *
 * This program may be freely distributed for class use, *
 * provided that this copyright notice is retained.      *
 *********************************************************/

/* inventory.c (Chapter 16, page 391) */
/* Maintains a parts database (array version) */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "readline.h"

#define NAME_LEN 25
#define MAX_PARTS 100

struct part {
  int number;
  char name[NAME_LEN+1];
  int on_hand;
} inventory[MAX_PARTS];

int num_parts = 0;   /* number of parts currently stored */

int find_part(int number);
void insert(void);
void search(void);
void update(void);
void print(void);

/**********************************************************
 * main: Prompts the user to enter an operation code,     *
 *       then calls a function to perform the requested   *
 *       action. Repeats until the user enters the        *
 *       command 'q'. Prints an error message if the user *
 *       enters an illegal code.                          *
 **********************************************************/
int main(void)
{
  char code;

  for (;;) {
    printf("Enter operation code: ");
    scanf(" %c", &code);
    while (getchar() != '\n')   /* skips to end of line */
      ;
    switch (code) {
      case 'i': insert();
                break;
      case 's': search();
                break;
      case 'u': update();
                break;
      case 'p': print();
                break;
      case 'q': return 0;
      default:  printf("Illegal code\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

/**********************************************************
 * find_part: Looks up a part number in the inventory     *
 *            array. Returns the array index if the part  *
 *            number is found; otherwise, returns -1.     *
 **********************************************************/
int find_part(int number)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < num_parts; i++)
    if (inventory[i].number == number)
      return i;
  return -1;
}

/**********************************************************
 * insert: Prompts the user for information about a new   *
 *         part and then inserts the part into the        *
 *         database. Prints an error message and returns  *
 *         prematurely if the part already exists or the  *
 *         database is full.                              *
 **********************************************************/
void insert(void)
{
  int part_number;

  if (num_parts == MAX_PARTS) {
    printf("Database is full; can't add more parts.\n");
    return;
  }

  printf("Enter part number: ");
  scanf("%d", &part_number);
  if (find_part(part_number) >= 0) {
    printf("Part already exists.\n");
    return;
  }

  inventory[num_parts].number = part_number;
  printf("Enter part name: ");
  read_line(inventory[num_parts].name, NAME_LEN);
  printf("Enter quantity on hand: ");
  scanf("%d", &inventory[num_parts].on_hand);
  num_parts++;
}

/**********************************************************
 * search: Prompts the user to enter a part number, then  *
 *         looks up the part in the database. If the part *
 *         exists, prints the name and quantity on hand;  *
 *         if not, prints an error message.               *
 **********************************************************/
void search(void)
{
  int i, number;

  printf("Enter part number: ");
  scanf("%d", &number);
  i = find_part(number);
  if (i >= 0) {
    printf("Part name: %s\n", inventory[i].name);
    printf("Quantity on hand: %d\n", inventory[i].on_hand);
  } else
    printf("Part not found.\n");
}

/**********************************************************
 * update: Prompts the user to enter a part number.       *
 *         Prints an error message if the part doesn't    *
 *         exist; otherwise, prompts the user to enter    *
 *         change in quantity on hand and updates the     *
 *         database.                                      *
 **********************************************************/
void update(void)
{
  int i, number, change;

  printf("Enter part number: ");
  scanf("%d", &number);
  i = find_part(number);
  if (i >= 0) {
    printf("Enter change in quantity on hand: ");
    scanf("%d", &change);
    inventory[i].on_hand += change;
  } else
    printf("Part not found.\n");
}

/**********************************************************
 * print: Prints a listing of all parts in the database,  *
 *        showing the part number, part name, and         *
 *        quantity on hand. Parts are printed in the      *
 *        order in which they were entered into the       *
 *        database.                                       *
 **********************************************************/
void print(void)
{
  int i;

  printf("Part Number   Part Name                  "
         "Quantity on Hand\n");
  for (i = 0; i < num_parts; i++)
    printf("%7d       %-25s%11d\n", inventory[i].number,
           inventory[i].name, inventory[i].on_hand);
}
```

File **readline.c**:

```
/*********************************************************
 * From C PROGRAMMING: A MODERN APPROACH, Second Edition *
 * By K. N. King                                         *
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 1996 W. W. Norton & Company, Inc. *
 * All rights reserved.                                  *
 * This program may be freely distributed for class use, *
 * provided that this copyright notice is retained.      *
 *********************************************************/

/* readline.c (Chapter 16, page 395) */

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "readline.h"

int read_line(char str[], int n)
{
  int ch, i = 0;

  while (isspace(ch = getchar()))
    ;
  while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    if (i < n)
      str[i++] = ch;
    ch = getchar();
  }
  str[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}
```

and **readline.h**:

```
/*********************************************************
 * From C PROGRAMMING: A MODERN APPROACH, Second Edition *
 * By K. N. King                                         *
 * Copyright (c) 2008, 1996 W. W. Norton & Company, Inc. *
 * All rights reserved.                                  *
 * This program may be freely distributed for class use, *
 * provided that this copyright notice is retained.      *
 *********************************************************/

/* readline.h (Chapter 16, page 395) */

#ifndef READLINE_H
#define READLINE_H

/**********************************************************
 * read_line: Skips leading white-space characters, then  *
 *            reads the remainder of the input line and   *
 *            stores it in str. Truncates the line if its *
 *            length exceeds n. Returns the number of     *
 *            characters stored.                          *
 **********************************************************/
int read_line(char str[], int n);

#endif
```

Comment: You are passing "compilation-type" `CFLAGS = -c -Wall` to your command that is linking the object files into your final binary. You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: You are trying to link ELF with `-c` option. Don't override implicit make's rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Make output:

```
cc -c -Wall inventory2.c -o inventory2.o
cc -c -Wall readline.c -o readline.o
cc -c -Wall readline.o inventory2.o -o inventory2
cc: warning: readline.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
cc: warning: inventory2.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

The command you are using to attempt to link the executable includes a `-c`. That's because you have `-c` in the flags.

Also the `run` recipe depends on a non-existing target.

Remove the `-o` from the compilationg commands and the `-c` from the linking commands.

```
############
# makefile #
############


CC=cc
CFLAGS=-Wall

BIN=inventory2


$(BIN): $(BIN).o readline.o #readline.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) readline.o $(BIN).o -o $(BIN)

$(BIN).o: $(BIN).c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN).c -c

readline.o: readline.c readline.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) readline.c -c

clean:
    $(RM) -rf $(BIN) *.dSYM
    $(RM) -rf readline.o
    $(RM) -rf $(BIN).o

run: $(BIN)
    ./$(BIN)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @giusti. I tried your solution but I get the following: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_read_line", referenced from:
      _insert in inventory2-b01b1e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [inventory2.o] Error 1`

Comment: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN).c` -> `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(BIN).c` and `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) readline.c` -> `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c readline.c`

Comment: I suggested you add `-c` to the recipe but didn't do it in the answer. But using implicit rules is better anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your Makefile by using implicit rules:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall

BIN = inventory2

.PHONY: run clean

$(BIN): $(BIN).o readline.o

readline.o: readline.h

clean:
    $(RM) $(BIN) *.o

run: $(BIN)
    -./$(BIN)
```

Comment: `.PHONY: run clean` is both redundant and useless, `$(BIN).o` also depends on `readline.h`

Comment: @chqrlie One of `.PHONY: run clean` was redundant (mistakenly copied) but second one is not useless. Try `touch clean` and then `make clean` without `.PHONY:` target. In original post `$(BIN).o` doesn't depend on `readline.h` so i left it as is. Correct dependency tracking is another topic.

Comment: *Try `touch clean`*... Of course if the project directory is boobytrapped, extra precautions are needed.  `touch GNUmakefile` is another way to waste the user's time.

Comment: Regarding `readline.h`, The user posted the source code, even without that this dependency is obvious and since you added one explicit rule, you might add both `:)`

Comment: thank you for your answer @dimich. What are the implicit rules?

Comment: @ecjb They are set of rules embedded into `make`. You can read about them [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html). Dump list of implicit rules and variables: `make -p -f /dev/null`